# Android Resource Linking Failed although i have all the resource files | Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, resources

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcFZT.png)

Whenever I run the app in emulator it shows the above error. But I have all the resource files.

[App Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J9p8.png)

dependencies showed in screenshot.
Other part of the gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.modshabuisness"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you clean and rebuild project? Would you please check xml selector `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`  more than one in your xml file , if had keep it single by removing others.