# AAPT: error: resource drawable/slider_custom_thumb (aka com.package.name:drawable/slider_custom_thumb) not found

Tags: android

Good Day,

The app was working fine, I did not touch or add new xml files. When I run the app again I got this error

```
AAPT: error: resource drawable/slider_custom_thumb (aka com.package.name:drawable/slider_custom_thumb) not found.
```

But the file is available on the drawable folder. Check below the codes for **slider_custom_thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
<size
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp" />
 </shape>
```

Comment: Would you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66702667

Comment: @ZahidIslam  it was fix already sir after posting it I was able to figure out the problem